# Java GAE + Gradle: Why is there no method called "fetchAsync()" in “com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchService"?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, build.gradle

I am new to GAE. I would like to use the asynchronous version of fetch (of package "com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.*"), which is named "fetchAsync()" according to API documentation at here:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/URLFetchService

But in my java code, it seems no method named "fetchAsync()" -- it says "Cannot resolve method 'fetchAsync(com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest)". Below is my java code:

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.bitesquad.com" + href);
HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest(url, HTTPMethod.GET);
HTTPResponse response = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService().fetchAsync(request);
```

I am sure that I imported everything needed because it is okay to run "fetch()". I am thinking about if I didn't include the appropriate version of GAE in my build.gradle or I missed anything in it. Or maybe Google didn't update the documentation? Below is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {    // Configuration for building
    repositories {
        jcenter()    // Bintray's repository - a fast Maven Central mirror & more
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:+'    // latest App Engine Gradle tasks
    }
}

repositories {   // repositories for Jar's you access in your code
    maven {
        url 'https://maven-central.storage.googleapis.com'             // Google's mirror of Maven Central
//   url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' // SNAPSHOT Repository (if needed)
    }
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'java'                              // standard Java tasks
apply plugin: 'war'                               // standard Web Archive plugin
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'  // App Engine tasks

dependencies {
    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version:'2.5'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine:+'

    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.3"
    compile "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5"
    compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0"

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.appengine/appengine-api-1.0-sdk
    compile group: 'com.google.appengine', name: 'appengine-api-1.0-sdk', version: '1.2.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

}

appengine {  // App Engine tasks configuration

    run {      // local (dev_appserver) configuration (standard environments only)
        port = 8080                 // default
    }

    deploy {   // deploy configuration
        stopPreviousVersion = true  // default - stop the current version
        promote = true              // default - & make this the current version
    }

    //tools.cloudSdkHome = '/Applications/google-cloud-sdk'
}

group 'xxx'
version 'xxx'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7  // App Engine Standard uses Java 7
targetCompatibility = 1.7  // App Engine Standard uses Java 7
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: review gradle script in following thread > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29673764/the-package-com-google-appengine-api-urlfetch-cannot-be-found

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: change the version to the newest one as follows:

```
compile group: 'com.google.appengine', name: 'appengine-api-1.0-sdk', version: '1.9.53'
```

(from 1.2 to 1.9)